# RabbitMQ SSL Connection with Apring AMQP 1.4.3

Tags: ssl, spring-amqp

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ over SSL. I have followed the RabbitMQ SSL documentation linked [here}(https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

As per RabbitMQ SSL documentation connecting using SSLv3 and TLSv1 is not recommeded due to known vulnerabilities. Due to this I have disabled these protocols on RabbitMQ as per instructions.

I am using Spring AMQP 1.4.3 to connect to RabbitMQ.

```java
ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/testConfig/testrabbit-context.xml");
RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
org.springframework.amqp.core.Message amqpMessage = new org.springframework.amqp.core.Message("Test".getBytes(), messageProperties);
String routingKey = "TEST.businessevent.route";
template.send(routingKey, amqpMessage);
```

My config:

```xml
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"        
    host="localhost" 
    port="5671" 
    username="username"
    password="password" 
    virtual-host="test_host" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" exchange="test_topic" />

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="test_topic" durable="true" />  

<bean id="clientConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
    <property name="sslPropertiesLocation" value="/testconfig/rabbitSSL.properties"/>
</bean>
```

`rabbitSSL.properties`:

```
keyStore=file:/client/keycert.p12
trustStore=file:/lib/security/rabbitStore
keyStore.passPhrase=testpassword
trustStore.passPhrase=testpassword
```

However when I use the above code and config to connect to RabbitMQ over SSL I am getting a fatal alert: protocol_version.

When I looked at the `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean` class that Spring is using to connect to RabbitMQ, I can see that the protocol appears to be hard coded to SSLv3.

```java
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
this.connectionFactory.useSslProtocol(context);
```

This code works fine if I do not disable SSLv3 on RabbitMQ. However I need to connect to RabbitMQ using Tlsv1.2. Can I do that using Spring AMQP 1.4.3 or do I need to use another version.

Thanks for any help you can provide me with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

While searching for RabbitMQ remote access I came across the below Spring `application.properties` configuration settings that can be done in Spring to configure the RabbitMQ connections.

https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Connect-to-SSL-enabled-RabbitMQ-server-Springboot/

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=hostURL
spring.rabbitmq.port = hostPort
spring.rabbitmq.username = username
spring.rabbitmq.password = password
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=virtualHost
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm=TLSv1.2
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-amqp#2-configuration

Answer (score 3):

I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-484) for this.

In the meantime, the `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean` is just a convenience class to make configuring an underlying connection factory more "Spring friendly" with defaults.

Instead, you can perform this initialization in your own code (perhaps using a `@Bean` declaration using Java Configuration).

Comment: Thanks!! Can this be done using Spring-boot?  We are currently not using spring-boot approach in our project, but if the protocol can be configured to TLSv1.2 using the spring-boot approach, we will try that instead. I have already tried by initializing RabbitMQ connectionFactory programmatically and setting the protocol in the SSLContext directly. That works fine but we were looking for a more Spring oriented approach.

Comment: No; it's not available in boot either; I have issued a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/267) for 1.5 and we will back-port it to 1.4.4 (with SSLv3 as the default). In the meantime, you can [grab my patched version](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/blob/AMQP-484/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java) and use it locally (just put it in your own package).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was trying to connect by Spring Boot application(2.1.4.RELEASE) that uses spring-boot-starter-amqp (2.1.4.RELEASE) to an AWS Managed instance of RabbitMQ aka Amazon MQ and it would fail with a similar error. What worked for me was setting these properties.

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm=TLSv1.3
```

Setting these properties explicitly was not required in an application that was using Spring Boot and spring-boot-starter-amqp (2.7.8) and they worked out of the box. Here's a mention of the same in Spring AMQP Documentation.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#rabbitconnectionfactorybean-configuring-ssl