# Can Spring Rabbitmq XML configuration of ssl properties "passPhrase" be compromised?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have used Spring Rabbitmq XML configuration in my project. To create the RabbitConnectionFactoryBean, we provide the ssl.properties file resource with below properties

```
keyStore=file:/secret/keycert.p12
trustStore=file:/secret/trustStore
keyStore.passPhrase=secret
trustStore.passPhrase=secret
```

The passPhrases are hardcoded values. We are worried that any one who gains access to the system can read this file and misuse it. It is true that the system admin and OS should protect these files, but this can be considered a security threat when untrusted user logs in.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903745/rabbitmq-ssl-connection-with-spring-amqp-1-4-3) link Gary suggests to use Java configuration and we can use that to create the RabbitConnectionFactoryBean and maybe read the encrypted passwords from system and use the setter to set them in the bean. 
But since we are already using XML configuration, is there any other ways to secure the passPhrases in the properties file?
Will this same configuration cause similar security issue in the PRODUCTION environment.? 
Kindly help me on how to achieve security on the above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is legal to say in the public, but I'll try.

There is some `security token` approach, when you start your project it requests such a token. An admin (or security representative) comes, inserts some special flesh drive, enter passwords. Your project reads properties from that device, populates all the properties and starts properly. That admin pulls flesh drive from USB and goes away. No one see password for your application!

The other solution you could consider is something like [Config Server](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html). So, your properties are stored somewhere outside of the current machine.

You also can really follow encryption way as well: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_encryption_and_decryption